# Issue with Maven Eclipse plugin and openjpa enhancement

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, openjpa

Our current project is integrating Spring 3/OpenJPA with Roo and maven on STS(Eclipse). The `M2E` plugin is a little problematic because it cannot handle entity enhancement.

So from programming side it is a little clumsy that we cannot build the whole project on Maven under Eclipse by one click, but have to let `STS(Eclipse)` to `build` the project first and then run `Ant` script to `enhance` the entities, then `refresh` the project, then `refresh` the `server deployment`. Not very effective.

I guess this is an issue for a while so create this thread to see if there is any updates.

There seems a tool available([OpenJPA Eclipse Tooling Builder](http://openjpa.apache.org/openjpaeclipseenhancementbuilder.html)) But it seems not supporting latest Eclipse(STS 2.9.1 is based on Eclipse 3.7, that tool only cover to 3.4).

So the question becomes: is there any way(or tools) we can integrate everything(`build`, `compile with enhancement`) together (possibly on Maven by only designing POM)?

Happy to learn any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Have you found a good solution? Everytime I change an entity it isn't automatically enhanced during the build proceeded by the IDE; I have to manually call Maven to do this.

Comment: @Caffé I haven't. So I use an Ant script for the job so I can call it form the UI. It looks the Maven Eclipse plugin still not happy with OpenJPA.. :(

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with eclipse kepler and OpenJPA 2.2.1.

The solution is quite simple, but a little dirty.

First of all, you need to install OpenJPA m2e connector from this site:

http://openjpa-maven-connector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/openjpa-connector-update-site

Next, you must modify your POM, and put, next to the  elemento of the openjpa-maven-plugin plugin (inside build element), the next definition:

```
<pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>openjpa-maven-plugin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

So the build element should looks like this (with your own entity package):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>mappingtool</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    com/xxxx/xxxx/*
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin definition only affects eclipse, not the mvn command execution -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>openjpa-maven-plugin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: The plugin management solution still works, thanks! But the url for the m2e connector is dead. We currently use this: https://github.com/beskow/openjpa-maven-connector/tree/master/openjpa-connector-update-site

Answer (score 0):

`@Subarule` I am not using Maven but only ANT for my project and the following ANT script helps to enhance my build.

```
    <target name="enhance" depends="compile">
    <echo message="Enhancing...."/>
    <!-- ***************************************************************************************************************** -->
    <!-- DO NOT DELETE FOLLOWING CODE. THIS IS ADDED FOR ENCHANCING THE CLASSES AT COMPILE TIME. IT IS REQUIRED BY OPENJPA -->
    <!-- Define the classpath to include the necessary files. -->
    <!-- ex. openjpa jars, persistence.xml, orm.xml, and target classes  -->
    <path id="jpa.enhancement.classpath">
        <!-- Assuming persistence.xml/orm.xml are in META-INF -->
        <pathelement location="META-INF" />

        <!-- Location of the .class files -->
        <pathelement location="${build.classes}" />

        <!-- Add the openjpa jars -->
        <fileset dir="OpenJPA_lib_jar">
                <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <!-- This is a bit of a hack, but I needed to copy the persistence.xml file from my src dir
         to the build dir when we run enhancement -->
    <!--<copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.launch, **/*.java"/>
    </copy>-->

    <!-- define the openjpac task; this can be done at the top of the -->
    <!-- build.xml file, so it will be available for all targets -->
    <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask" classpathref="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />

    <!-- invoke enhancer on all .class files below the model directory -->
    <openjpac>
        <classpath refid="jpa.enhancement.classpath" />
        <fileset dir=".">
            <include name="**/model/*.class" />
        </fileset>
        <config propertiesFile = "${basedir}/src/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    </openjpac>
    <echo message="Enhancement complete" />
    <!-- ***************************************************************************************************************** -->
</target>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually I run enhancement via Ant as well but I really hope to find a solution to make everything happen by Maven/Pom.